# default behavior is automatically copy a highlighted text to clipboard; can I disable this?

Tags: clipboard

When I highlight a piece of text by dragging the cursor over it, Ubuntu automatically copies this text to the clipboard. I want to disable this behaviour such that after I highlight the text, I need to right click (option click) on the text and select "copy". Is this possible?

Comment: Are you seeing this behaviour in *all* applications? Or is this something you see in Terminal and want to prevent?

Comment: Which applications do you see this in?  This is a PuTTY default and a Windows Command Line default.  In ubuntu terminal this is not a default.  What Ubuntu version are you using, and which applications explicitly are seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question: The behaviour I asked about is the result of my use of a clipboard manager program "CopyQ". In the preferences for that program was "store text selected using mouse". That was checked by default. When I un checked it, the behaviour stopped.

Answer (score 0):

With Kubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic) the problem has been the clipboard manager of the Plasma Shell. Right-click on the clipboard icon right below in the task bar, select "Configure..." (or so) and then uncheck

> [  ] Keep the selection and clipboard the same

in the general tab/row (the first one).